# angular ng-repeat dosen't wait for scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

html

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in timesheets">{{item.week}}</div>
```

script

```
    .controller('TimesheetMainCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $window) {

    dpd.timesheetold.get(function (result, err) {

        if (err) return console.log(err);
        $scope.timesheets = result;
        console.log($scope.timesheets);
    })
});
```

timesheets loads from a rest api, but it seams like ng-repeat dosen't wait for the scope.

if i set timesheets to a value, ng repeat runs it.

so how do i tell ng-repeat to wait for scope to be loaded ?

Comment: does `dpd.timesheetold.get` has implemented with `$http`/`$resource`/`$q` or is that ajax going from other plugin?

Comment: what does `result` look like and where is the service code for `timesheetold.get`. Not enough information given

Comment: dpd is a rest script generatet by deployd

Comment: ok... then that is outside of angular core and solution provided below should work. Anything that changes scope outside of angulaar has to notify angular to run digest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `dpd.timesheetold.get` is an async call and it doesn't trigger a `$digest` cycle - so your view never updates. You can manually trigger one with `$timeout`

```
.controller('TimesheetMainCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $window, $timeout) {

    dpd.timesheetold.get(function (result, err) {

        if (err) return console.log(err);
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.timesheets = result;
        });
        //console.log($scope.timesheets);
    })
});
```

Comment: nice, this worked then i just have to manually trigger with timeout each time i use dpd ?

Comment: @ThomasBlauenfeldt -- Yeah.. anytime you use a 3rd party module that isn't injected - chances are it won't trigger a `$digest` cycle - so you'll need to take care of that.